# Android NDK - CMake build environment variables

Tags: android-ndk, cmake

I am writing Android library using NDK (C++) and CMake toolchain.

CMake toolchain file that I am using is from Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake instead of Android/sdk/cmake. As later is not updated and recommended (?).

I am running into problem where I am only able to set arguments via command line invocation but not from CMakeLists.txt file.

My command line is:

```
# Generate required build environment
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$ANDROID_NDK/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
      -DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE \
      -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL="android-21"
cmake --build .
```

However if I set this argument in CMakeLists.txt as below:

```
set(ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL "android-21")
```

then it is not configured correctly.

So, what is recommended and correct way to setup ANDROID variables in CMake toolchain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess for why configuring that in the CMakeLists.txt itself doesn't work is that toolchain files are kind of weird; cmake really doesn't want toolchain files to be configurable, but for Android they are.

> So, what is recommended and correct way to setup ANDROID variables in CMake toolchain?

As you've done, from the command line. If using Studio, these would be specified in the gradle file rather than in cmake.

> CMake toolchain file that I am using is from Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake instead of Android/sdk/cmake. As later is not updated and recommended (?).

Correct. The one bundled with the NDK is the one to use.